# Start VsCode gdb debugger with F10 or Ctrl+F10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

### My setup

```
λ code --version
1.61.2
6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643
x64
```

```
λ code --list-extensions
adpyke.codesnap
astallinger.sourcetrail
eamodio.gitlens
errata-ai.vale-server
GitHub.github-vscode-theme
marus25.cortex-debug
matklad.rust-analyzer
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
trond-snekvik.gnu-mapfiles
vrjuliao.sml-environment
vscodevim.vim
```

### My problem

I've mapped Ctrl+F10 to run to cursor.

I can step with <kbd>F10</kbd> and run to cursor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

But I can't start a debugging session with those keys. Especially starting a program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> would be very useful to me, since it gives me a REPL-kind of workflow when using the debugger. Setting stopAtEntry : true in launch.json, allows me to run to main by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> but that doesn't help with my run to cursor use case.

How do I start a debugging session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>?